# Which states have weakened police unions’ collective bargaining power over disciplinary issues?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, police, labor-union

Matt Yglesias, liberal political columnist for *Vox*, just tweeted [this](https://twitter.com/mattyglesias/status/1292131884806348801?s=21):

> Months into the era of everyone reading White Fragility and posting Black Lives Matter memes and declaring racism a public health emergency have any states voted to weaken police unions’ collective bargaining powers over disciplinary issues?

My question is, what are “police unions’ collective bargaining powers over disciplinary issues”?  Does it mean that police unions negotiate with city/state governments not only over wages and working conditions, but also over the ability to fire police officers for disciplinary issues?

Also, Yglesias may have been asking his question sarcastically, but what is the answer to it?  Which states if any have weakened police unions’ collective bargaining powers over disciplinary issues since the George Floyd protests began?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this at the moment, but you might want to look at this [Duke law article](https://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3890&context=dlj), which claims that most states allow police unions to use collective bargaining for disciplinary issues. It was written in 2017, so it won't reflect anything post-Floyd, but it might be a good starting point.